# .htaccess: картинка без расширения

Tags: .htaccess, изображения

Есть категория `/i/`, в неё попадают мои скриншоты, имена которых состоят из цифр и латинских букв (и строчные, и заглавные). Всего символов от 1 до 30. Плюс потом расширение файла (jpg|png и т.п., т.е. картинки).

Я хочу делиться короткой ссылкой без расширения файла картинки, но чтоб по этой короткой ссылке картинка открывалась.

- Есть ссылка: http://site.ru/i/nx7qc.png
- Нужна такая: http://site.ru/i/nx7qc

Много вариантов перепробовал, никак не получается. Последний мой вариант выглядит так:

```
RewriteCond i\/([a-zA-Z0-9+]{1,30})\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$
RewriteRule ^\/i\/%1
```

Подскажите, как правильно написать? Или, может, надо ещё в php что-то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.jpg -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.jpg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.jpeg -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.jpeg
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gif -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.gif
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.png -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.png
```

Comment: Прочитав, я сразу хотел написать, что тут явно не то, но оно сработало! Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$` - попробуйте так.

Comment: Не срабатывает. Происходит редирект на корневую директорию почему-то.